# What is the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$?

Tags: functions, inverse

please help me to find out the inverse this function,
    $$f(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$$
I know that, let
    $$y=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}$$
and if I find $x=\cdots$ then that is the inverse. But I can't calculate this. Is this the only way. is there any other way to figure it out?

Comment: This is the hyperbolic cotangent function, and its inverse is the inverse hyperbolic cotangent function.

Comment: Replace $e^x$ with some other letter, say, $u$; notice that $e^{-x}$ is just $1/u$; now you have a formula for $y$ in terms of $u$; can you solve that formula for $u$?

Answer (score 4):

Applying [Componendo and dividendo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Componendo_and_dividendo) on $$\frac y1=\frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}},$$

we get

$$\frac{y+1}{y-1}=\frac{e^x}{e^{-x}}=e^{2x}$$

$$2x=\ln\left(\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right)$$

Comment: Where did that absolute value come from?  If $e^{2x}=\dfrac{y+1}{y-1}$ then $2x = \ln\dfrac{y+1}{y-1}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy,sorry for the wrong notation.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
y = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}.
$$
Multiplying the top and bottom by $e^x$, you get
$$
y = \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}.
$$
The advantage of this form is that $x$ now appears ONLY within the expression $e^{2x}$, so we can treat $e^{2x}$ as the unknown that we're trying to solve for.

Now clearing fractions, we get
$$
(e^{2x}-1)y = e^{2x}+1
$$
so
$$
e^{2x}y - y = e^{2x}+1
$$
and then
$$
e^{2x}y -e^{2x} = y+1.
$$
From this we get
$$
e^{2x}(y-1) = y+1.
$$
Then
$$
e^{2x} = \frac{y+1}{y-1},
$$
$$
2x = \ln \frac{y+1}{y-1},
$$
$$
x = \frac 1 2 \ln \frac{y+1}{y-1}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ f(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}} = \frac{2\cosh(x)}{2\sinh(x)} = \frac{1}{\tanh(x)} = \coth(x) $$

therefore,

$$ f^{-1}(x)= \operatorname{arccoth}(x) $$