# Find the inverse of f, where $f(x)= \frac {e^x - e^{-x}} {e^x + e^{-x}} $

Tags: functions, inverse

[image]I have tried letting $y= f(x)^{-1}$

So, f(y) = x

${\frac {e^y - e^{-y}}{e^y + e^{-y}}= x}$

Then, multiplying the top and bottom by $e^y$, ${\frac {e^y(e^y - e^{-y})}{e^y(e^y + e^{-y})}= x}$

${\frac {e^{2y} -1}{e^{2y} +1}= x}$

$e^{2y} -1 = x (e^{2y}+1)$

$e^{2y} -1= e^{2y}x + x$

$e^{2y} (1-x) = x+1$

Therefore, $e^{2y} = \frac {x+1}{1-x}$

$2y=ln (\frac {x+1}{1-x})$

$y= \frac{1}{2} ( \frac {x+1}{1-x})$

$f^{-1} (x) =\frac {1}{2} ln (\frac {1+x}{1-x})$

The answer for the inverse from the book is $f^{-1} (x) =\frac {1}{2} ln (\frac {1+x}{x-1})$

So, I can’t seem to get the positive sign for x in the denominator.

There’s another very similar question in Maths Stack Exchange, but the positive and negative signs are different : [What is the inverse of $f(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669143/what-is-the-inverse-of-fx-fracexe-xex-e-x)

Please help me solve this. Thank you

Comment: Did you graph your inverse against the given function? They should be symmetric with respect to $y=x$.

Comment: Yes, i have and they’re not symmetric...so I’m guessing the answer given is incorrect...could you help me get the correct answer, or is mine correct already? Please help me me check. Thank you so much

Comment: After a quick look (and I did an edit), I don't see anything wrong. So did you check YOUR answer against the given function? Are they symmetric with respect to $y=x$?

Comment: Yep, my answer’s symmetric... thank you @imranfat

Comment: @Gigi I don't see anything wrong with your method and, when numerically evaluated, it gives correct results. So it sounds like it could be a mistake in the book. What book are you using?

Comment: Maybe that’s a typo in the book. Note that your function has value $|y|<1$, so the domain of the inverse function should be something like $|x|<1$. Try to google with the key word “inverse hyperbolic tangent” to get more information.

Comment: Ok thank you @Pythagoras

Comment: i think it is $ 1-x$ in denominator

Comment: One can see that the book’s answer is manifestly wrong, without doing any computation. Since the range of the original is $\langle-1,1\rangle$, the inverse function must be defined for $x\in\langle-1,1\rangle$. Yet the book’s formula is undefined for such $x$: the log needs a positive input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is wrong. If you put y=f(x) then 
$$ 1-y= 2e^{-x}/(e^x+e^{-x}) $$  , which is positive, and
$$ 1+y = 2e^x/(e^x+e^{-x}) $$ ,which is also positive so the book wouldd be trying totake the ln of a negative number. Your methodology is completely correct and your answer is right.